# Optimize a zscore algorithm

Tags: performance, algorithm, ruby, statistics

I wrote a zscore algorithm in Ruby that runs fine, but is incredibly slow when I have 8000+ entries to score. Can anyone help me figure out a way to improve my code, please?

```
module Enumerable  
  def mean
    reduce(:+).to_f / length
  end

  def sample_variance
    sum = inject(0){ |acc, i| acc + (i - mean)**2 }
    1 / length.to_f * sum
  end

  def standard_deviation
    Math.sqrt(sample_variance)
  end

  def zscore
    if standard_deviation.zero?
      Array.new(length, 0)
    else
      collect { |v| (v - mean) / standard_deviation } 
    end
  end
end
```

The float is giving every score an accuracy of up to 17 decimal places.  Would making it only 8 decimal places speed things up?

**EDIT:**
Here is an updated version of the algorithm given the advice received in this thread.

```
class Array
  def mean(len=self.length)
    reduce(:+).to_f / len
  end

  def sample_variance
    len = length
    m = mean(len)
    sum = reduce { |acc, i| acc + (i - m)**2 }
    sum.to_f / len
  end

  def standard_deviation
    Math.sqrt(sample_variance)
  end

  def zscore
    stdev = standard_deviation
    m = mean
    stdev.zero? ? Array.new(length, 0) : collect { |v| (v - m) / stdev }
  end
end
```

Comment: If that is a sample variance (as opposed to a population variance), you need to divide by n-1 (not n) for it to be an unbiased estimator (though in this case the difference is negligible). Also, I suggest you write that `sum / (length + 1.0)`.

Comment: @CarySwoveland I'm not a very mathy person...would you be so kind as to explain why I need to do `sum/(length + 1.0)` for sample variance? Thanks! Also, this is a population variance as I am running it on all records.

Comment: Unfortunately, it's a [mathy answer](http://isites.harvard.edu/fs/docs/icb.topic515975.files/Proof%20that%20Sample%20Variance%20is%20Unbiased.pdf). I think `sum.to_f / len` reads better than `1 / len.to_f * sum`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is here: `collect { |v| (v - mean) / standard_deviation }`. `standard_deviation` is constant but, being inside a block, it is called on each iteration. Set the value to a local variable before. As noted by Flambino, the same principle applies to `sample_variance` (which uses `mean` inside a block).

In a functional language (where immutability is honored) the compiler would be able to do the right thing, but not in an imperative language plagued with side-effects like Ruby.

Some additional notes to your code:

- `module Enumerable`: But you call `.length`, which is not a method that an enumerable is required to implement. Consider adding them to `Array` (which includes `Enumerable`).
- `reduce` and then `inject`. I'd use just one of the alias.

Comment: I actually just noticed this before you wrote it. Setting standard_deviation to a variable at the beginning of the zscore method makes this run blazingly fast. Thanks

Comment: @DaniG2k You can do the same local var trick with `mean` in your `zscore` and `sample_variance` methods. Not as big a boost as storing `standard_deviation`, but the principle's the same

Comment: @tokland I'm confused: the `reduce` method should be called on an `Enumerable` but `length` should be called on an `Array`. Which is better to use?

Comment: @DaniG2k: `Array` includes `Enumerable`.